# Accessing GetConsoleHistoryInfo() from managed code

Tags: c#, winapi, console-application, dllimport, managed

I've got a vaguely Java background and just installed Visual Studio Community 2015. Playing about with it so have a console app up and running and wanted to use above function after attaching to a different Console. Trouble is I have no idea about the appropriate declaration for this function - can someone tell me what it should be in this instance but also a good pointer for me in future so I can work it out on my own. The IDE doesn't seem to help much

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetConsoleHistoryInfo();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                    GetConsoleHistoryInfo(); // <-- PInvokeStackImbalance occurred
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetConsoleHistoryInfo(ref CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO ConsoleHistoryInfo);
```

You will need the CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO type too for this to work:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO
{
    uint cbSize;
    uint HistoryBufferSize;
    uint NumberOfHistoryBuffers;
    uint dwFlags;
}
```

A lot of useful PInvoke information can be found at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetConsoleHistoryInfo). You should however double check it against the MSDN to see if it fits.

Comment: thanks - where is the best resource to get such info?

Comment: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) is the crappiest resource for P/Invoke there is. Period. It is stock full of wrong, and this structure declaration is no exception: The native data type `UINT` is 32 bits, and does **not** map to C#'s `ushort` (16 bits). See [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) for a reliable reference.

Comment: @IInspectable hm, seems you are right. That's strange, it was pretty reliable once.

Comment: No. It has **not ever been reliable**. Not at any point in time, not in this universe. To this date you can be pretty confident, that the majority of declarations is not ready for 64-bit platforms.

Comment: The parameter should be `ref` rather than `out`. Since `cbSize` is passed in to the function. Use MSDN and the headers to get the C++ declarations, and translate them.